# Charmichael numbers problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $n$. 
 It is known that 
$$a^n-a$$
 is divisible by $n$ for each positive integer $a\in \{2015,2016,...,2014^2\}$.

Show that for all integers $a\in \{1,2,3,...,4056208\}$
$$a^n-a$$
is divisible by $n$.

Comment: What is the question ? 
You want us to solve the problem ? At least ask politely...

Comment: If $(ab)^n=ab$ and $a^n=a$ (mod n), then $b^n=b$ (mod n) if $a$ has no common factors with $n$.